# How to remove this line from visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

How do you hide the ruler in Visual Studio 2013?

I tried to disable the Productivity Power tools (Column guides option) but it's still there.

[image: Remove the ruler]

Thank you.

Comment: Open the picture in paint and use the eraser tool :-D

Comment: I looked everywhere but couldn't find anything nor reproduce it. Is that set in column 73? When did this line appear? Is it only in .cs files? You don't have any other extension installed?

Comment: Yes, thank you.
it was Visual Assist X extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a Visual Assist option.

so i just uncheck it on :

VASSISTX > Visual Assist X Options > Advanced > Display indicator after column.

[image: Screenshot]